# Is "in an utter attempt" correct?

Tags: phrases, articles

I think I have heard, and I think to understand, the phrase "in an utter attempt". I want to say something like "In an utter attempt for brevity, I will summarize each chapter in one sentence". Is this correct to say?

Comment: It is grammatical, but it makes little sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such phrase "In an utter attempt".

[image: NGram for in an utter attempt showing zero results]

You could be confusing "utter attempt" with "utter contempt". The latter meaning complete disregard for proper courtroom behaviour and procedure, or a severe lack of consideration in general.

You sentence would make more sense if you use *utter* to modify brevity, rather than attempt:

> In an attempt for utter brevity, I will summarize each chapter in one sentence

*Utter* in this context means *complete* or *absolute*.

Comment: +1, but frankly I'd take `utter` out of that suggested sentence too, (unless you are trying to be ironic). It doesn't really strengthen the concept of "brevity" appreciably, and makes the sentence ... less brief. It kinda puts the lie to your professed concern for brevity when you are throwing in unneeded words. Better would be `In the interest of brevity...`

Comment: @T.E.D I agree.